# Explain the statement related int *count for the algorithm

Tags: c

I want to make a program to find the repeating integers in an array.
For that I had 2 methods.

- Use nested array. it will give a time complexity of O(n²)
- Use an auxiliary array to find the frequency of an array.

I have seen a solution, but it is limited to only 1 digit number. It uses a count array.

```
int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (size - 2));
```

Why is it (`size -2`)?

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void printDuplicate(int arr[], int size){
    int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int),(size-2));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(count[arr[i]] == 1)
            printf("%d,",arr[i]);
        else
            count[arr[i]]++;
    }
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {2,5,3,4,2,5,7,8,7};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printDuplicate(arr,size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is assigned to `size`?

Comment: Might I suggest adding a C/C++ tag to this to get more response?

Comment: Maybe it could help you: [calloc reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/)

Comment: "size" is the number of elements in the actual array i.e. Array that is containing the numbers or data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `calloc` statement writen here is wrong. Here the memory allocation is

`4*7=28`

So here the memory allocation is for `7` integers but here you can access more that 7 elements. It is actually wrong in `C` language but it works fine with now a days compilers as `C` has no array boundary checking but it may cause to write invalid memory.

> But how you are able to access the memory blocks which are not allocated?

This answer is explained in the best way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why).

You can see the code I compiled [here](http://ideone.com/fS4XLw).

And when we decode the algorithm you can see that

1. For `i=0` the `arr[0]=2`. And then it checks whether the `count[2]==1` or not as `count[2]` represents the number of repetitions for the number `2`. As for the first time `count[2]=0` so it increments the value to `1`
2. Then it check for all `i` values.
3. When `i=4` then it checks whether `count[arr[4]]` which is `count[2]==1` or not. If it is one then it prints it.

Comment: decoding is OK. But first part is wrong i.e. size is maximum value in array.

Comment: So what was the purpose of `(size-2)`? I couldn't relate any thing to this @user3481574

Comment: I changed the answer you can check now

Comment: hmm. This is not so good in C indeed I can co-op with it. Thanks Anyway. This problem irritated me. And as the Ratings on this question is negative I have started thinking that the question was really stupid.

Comment: yeah.. the time I asked the question is the time when I joined StackOverflow

Comment: There are some rules visit the link to know the rules @user381574

Answer (score 0):

Following comments show actual reason of each parameter for `calloc` function

```
int *count = 
(int *)
calloc(
    sizeof(int), // Number of elements to allocate
    (size-2) // Size of each element
);
```

I guess that your parameters are reversed

If you have:

```
int *count = (int *)calloc((size - 2), sizeof(int));
```

It would allocate an `int` array with `size - 2` elements, each one with size of an `int`

But I think that this number of elements (`size - 2`) will be not enough for your program.

See your example (with reversed parameters):

...

```
int arr[] = {2,5,3,4,2,5,7,8,7}; // This array has 9 elements
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); // So size will 9
printDuplicate(arr,size); // arr and 9 as parameters
```

...

```
int *count = (int *)calloc((size-2), sizeof(int)); // You allocated a 7-size array
```

...

```
if(count[arr[i]] == 1) // Maximum index of count will be 8
// so the allocated memory will be not enough
```

...

Source: [calloc reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/)

Comment: No. You can execute the same code for input                                            int arr[] = {2,5,3,4,2,5,7,8,7,9,9}; the output is OK. You can check it on gcc. And the parameters I have passed in calloc are also correct, no error found by gcc, not even affecting the program.

Comment: I believe that @Subinoy answer (and edit) explains why there is no error on gcc.

Comment: Try to use a really big number (in my machine under 3000) in `arr[]` and you will have memory invasion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *count = (int *)calloc((size - 2), sizeof(int));
```

`size -2` is not required, this is confused statement please avoid to use this.

Create memory as use all. Instead of `size-2` we can use direct size of the array.

It won't make an error. Thank you.

Enjoy the learning this session.